# I purchased my domain with namecheap, have hosting from nearlyfreespeech - how do I get my site up and running?

Tags: hosting, domain-name

I bought my domain from namecheap a week or so ago. Today, I bought hosting from nearly free speech and have built my site. I've uploaded my site to the nearly free speech servers.

I can access my site at mysite.nsfhost.com. On Nearly free speech, it says that the associated domain is mysite.com

But I didn't change anything on the namecheap side of things, and I have no idea how to point mysite.com to the nsfhost.com

Help!

Comment: Who is going to host your name service? Nearly free speech, namecheap, or someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namecheap has a DNS control panel. All you need to do is set up an [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) for your domain that points to the IP address of your nsfhost server. There is a video on setting up an A record using the namecheap control panel [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhHiwh9tNRo)